# Mapping xml using Smooks

Tags: xml

I have the following XML, to be mapped to the mentioned class:

```
<xml>
 <list>
  <a>1</a>
  <a>2</a>
  <a>3</a>
 </listt>

 <list>
  <b>1</b>
  <b>2</b>
  <b>3</b>
 </listt>
</xml>

class xml {
 List<A> aList;
 List<b> bList;
}
```

How to map this using smooks as what I have did gives me a null "aList" , I think it can't distinguish between first and second `List`:

```
<jb:bean beanId="xml" class="xml" createOnElement="xml">
  <jb:wiring property="aList" beanIdRef="aList" />
  <jb:wiring property="bList" beanIdRef="bList"/>
</jb:bean>

<jb:bean beanId="aList" class="java.util.ArrayList" createOnElement="list">
  <jb:wiring beanIdRef="a" beanType="A/>
</jb:bean>

<jb:bean beanId="bList" class="java.util.ArrayList" createOnElement="list">
  <jb:wiring beanIdRef="b" beanType="B/>
</jb:bean>

<jb:bean beanId="a" class="A" createOnElement="a">
...
</jb:bean>

<jb:bean beanId="b" class="B" createOnElement="b">
...
</jb:bean>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks A LOT

Answer (score 1):

Create only one list and wire to it both A and B listss mapping a and b values, in the end you'll have them all in your List anyway.